# Clipping and scaling an image within an ellipse (not the ellipse itself)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to find a way to clip an image with an ellipse so that *if I scale the image, I keep the ellipse intact*, but so far I've had no luck.

Here's my XAML:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Clip>
    <RectangleGeometry x:Name="ClippingRectangle"
                       Rect="0,0,200,200"/>
  </Grid.Clip>
  <Ellipse Stretch="UniformToFill"
           x:Name="ImageEllipse"
           SizeChanged="ImageEllipse_OnSizeChanged">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SomePath}>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
  </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

I'm using the `SizeChanged` event to update the size of the clipping rectangle.
The problem is that this way the outer `Grid` clips the `Ellipse`, along with its image, so the result is a scaled circle with cropped edges.
Instead, I want to just scale the image *inside* the ellipse.

The problem is that the `Ellipse` control is a shape, so I can't add an actual `Image` control inside it and scale that one instead.
Is there a way to actually do this, or since Microsoft decided to restrict the clipping property to just `RectangleGeometry` objects, there's no way to do this?

Same problem when using a `Border`, as the `CornerRadius` property only applies to its background and it doesn't actually clip its content.

Thanks!

**EDIT #1** - As requested, here's the result I get when scaling the `Ellipse`:
[image]

**EDIT #2** - I've tried animating the `ImageBrush` like this:

```
<ImageBrush.Transform>
  <ScaleTransform x:Name="AvatarTransform"
                  CenterY="0.5"
                  CenterX="0.5"/>
  </ImageBrush.Transform>
</ImageBrush.Transform>
```

And then:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="TestAnimation">
  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="AvatarTransform"
                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                   To="1.2" Duration="0:0:1"/>
</Storyboard>
```

But nothing seems to happen for some reason, I'm not even sure it's actually possible to animate the `Transform` property of a `Brush`, since it's *not* an `UIElement` object

**EDIT #3** - Here's an example of what I want to achieve with an animation:
[image]

**EDIT #4** - From two answers, I tried to animate the `ImageBrush.Translate` property again like this:

```
<!--Image XAML-->
<ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"
            ImageSource="/SomeImage.jpg">
  <ImageBrush.Transform>
    <CompositeTransform x:Name="MyTransform"/>
  </ImageBrush.Transform>
</ImageBrush>

<!--Image storyboard-->
<Storyboard x:Name="ScaleStory">
  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyTransform"
                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                   From="1" To="1.4" Duration="0:0:1"/>
</Storyboard>
```

But it still isn't working. Plus, with this approach I can't set the `RenerTransformOrigin` property, since I don't have an `UIElement` to work with, so even if the animation did work, the image would be scaled to the right and to the bottom, and that isn't the expected result.

**Edit #4 >> SOLVED!** - As seen in the answer marked as valid, here's my code:

```
<Ellipse Stretch="UniformToFill"
         x:Name="ImageEllipse">
  <Ellipse.Fill>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/SomePath/SomeImage.jpg">
      <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <CompositeTransform CenterY="0.5"
                            CenterX="0.5"/>
      </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
    </ImageBrush>
  </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

It turns out it works with the `Ellipse.Fill` property too, so I didn't have to switch to a `PathGeometry` to create the circle that clips the image.

Comment: could you provide screen with actual result ?

Comment: Can't you just use `ImageBrush.Transform` to transform just the image?

Comment: @AndriiKrupka I've updated the question with the requested image

Comment: @DecadeMoon I was using the UI.Composition namespace for the animations so I didn't think about that. I tried using a simple DoubleAnimation, but still no luck there (see updated question)

Comment: What do you do in `ImageEllipse_OnSizeChanged`?

Comment: @AndriiKrupka Oh, there I just update the clipping rectangle to make sure it has the same size of the Grid/Ellipse

Comment: provide a few images with expected result. hard to understand what you want in final/

Comment: @AndriiKrupka You're right, I've just updated my question with a sample image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation I am using to do this:  Place these resources in your Page (XAML side)

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardZoomIn">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(Brush.RelativeTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="path">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1"
                                  Value="1.5">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(Brush.RelativeTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="path">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1"
                                  Value="1.5">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardZoomOut">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(Brush.RelativeTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="path">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1"
                                  Value="1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(Brush.RelativeTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="path">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1"
                                  Value="1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
```

Now, here is the rest of the view.  It is a grid, two buttons, the canvas and paths within.

```
   <Grid Width="1000"
      Height="1000">
    <StackPanel>

        <Button Content="Zoom In" Click="ButtonZoomIn_Click" />
        <Button Content="Zoom Out" Click="ButtonZoomOut_Click"/>

    </StackPanel>

    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Width="500"
            Height="500"
            Grid.RowSpan="2">

        <Path x:Name="path">
            <Path.Fill>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"
                            ImageSource="12019035.jpg">
                    <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform CenterY="0.5"
                                            CenterX="0.5"
                                            ScaleX="1.5"
                                            ScaleY="1.5" />
                    </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </ImageBrush>
            </Path.Fill>
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure IsClosed="True"
                                StartPoint="0, 250">
                        <ArcSegment Size="1, 1"
                                    Point="500, 250"
                                    SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"
                                    IsLargeArc="True" />
                        <ArcSegment Size="1, 1"
                                    Point="0, 250"
                                    SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"
                                    IsLargeArc="True" />
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>

    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Now in the code behind (which I hate code behind and recommend MVVM)...

```
 private void ButtonZoomIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     => (Resources["StoryboardZoomIn"] as Storyboard)?.Begin();

 private void ButtonZoomOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     => (Resources["StoryboardZoomOut"] as Storyboard)?.Begin();
```

This will animate the image, clipped within the ellipse, starting from a center point on the image.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm sorry again, but this isn't working for me, looks like the animations on the ImageBrush.Transform don't work. At least, I tried with two Storyboards both in XAML and in code behind and they didn't do anything. Plus, with this approach there's no way to set the RenderTransformOrigin, so even if the animation did work, the image would end up being scaled to the right instead of at the center. I'm starting to think this just isn't doable on UWP, at least from XAML...

Comment: No, I am animating the image on my UWP and it is centered.  Let me post more code in a bit.

Comment: Ok, I am going to edit this answer to show the more code.  This is working for UWP.

Comment: I sent the entire code.  Please mark as answered if you're happy with it.

Comment: Of course I will, just let me test this (it's 3am here, let's say tomorrow) so I can confirm that it does in fact answer my question - it sure looks like it this time though. And man, you really are dedicated, thanks! :)

Comment: It works perfectly! I was also able to keep using the Ellipse, and I used your Storyboards to animate the inner Image, I didn't have to switch to a PathGeometry, so that turned out even better than expected, thank you so much!

Comment: Oh well crap lol.  I didn't even try the ellipse you had.  I just assumed it wasn't clipped lol.  Good work man.  Makes sense now that I smack myself in the head because the Ellipse is really just a shape of those paths more or less already built in.

Comment: Just a heads up, because sometimes sorting through the different processes to create storyboards and crap can get exhausting... Just remembering all the exact paths to use and all... You can right click on your project in Solution Explorer and choose 'Design in Blend...' and the project will open in Blend as well.  From there designing triggers, animations, styles, etc. is a breeze.  I was taught to manually create storyboards from code and from XAML and knowing that is MASSIVE but to be quick and accurate Blend get's it done.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the Clip to a be a PathGeometry as opposed to RectangleGeometry and the clipping will work.  Here's an example of an image that can zoom in and out and stay within the clipped region.  Play with this until it works for you.

```
    <Grid Width="1000"
          Height="1000">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Width="500"
          Height="500">
        <Grid.Clip>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure IsClosed="True"
                            StartPoint="0, 250">
                    <ArcSegment Size="1, 1"
                                Point="500, 250"
                                SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"
                                IsLargeArc="True" />
                    <ArcSegment Size="1, 1"
                                Point="0, 250"
                                SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"
                                IsLargeArc="True" />
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Grid.Clip>

        <Image Source="12019035.jpg"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.2"
                                    ScaleY="1.2" />
                    <SkewTransform />
                    <RotateTransform />
                    <TranslateTransform />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I just put a grid inside of a grid so that the sizes would be correct for this example.

I clipped the inner grid so that it was a perfect ellipse using paths.  Feel free to copy that segment and use it as needed obviously.  You will just need to adjust the sizes etc. to match your own view.

In order to zoom the image in and out for this example you need to animate or directly manipulate the ScaleTransform Scale.X and Scale.Y properties on the image where the value is a double with 1 being 100%, 1.5 150%, etc.

If you're not sure how to use paths I may be able to explain but there are examples out there.  It's basically starting point on the PathFigure object, and the point on every segment inside the PathFigure is the next point you wish to meet.  Here I start at 0, 250 and draw an arc to point 500, 250.  I then draw another arc to 0, 250 completing the ellipse.  It works with these numbers because the grid width / height is 500, 500.

The cool thing about this is you can draw a shape or clip any UIElement with any pattern you wish :)  It could be a star, or some crazy other shape.  This is what you're looking for but have some fun with it!

Comment: I'm sorry, but as I stated in my question, the Clip property value can only be a RectangleGeometry object from WinRT on, so this method won't work on UWP

Comment: You are correct... Well that stinks.  I'll keep digging because there must be a way.